# Why after some succesful use suddenly the SSH login in the EC2 wont work

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, centos

I have logged to the EC2 via SSH with PPK file several times, until it suddenly wont let me log in and write "Server refused our key".

Tried to create a new PPK file from the PEM file, but it still wont let me login.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with Redhat AMI's that extra lines get added to the sshd_config and ssh does not start properly.

To fix this you will have to detach the root volume of the instance attach it to another instance as a secondary volume and then modify the etc/ssh/sshd_config file and remove the following lines if present:

```
UseDNS no 

PermitRootLogin without-password
```

After this you have to edit the /etc/rc.d/rc.local file
you have to remove the following lines from the end of the file

```
cat <<EOL >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
UseDNS no
PermitRootLogin without-password
```

After you do this you can detatch the volume from the other instance and re-mount it on your original instance and you should be able to SSH into it